# Optimizing repetitive GROUP BY in multiple subqueries in INNER JOINs

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Right, so I have this clunky query that I need to optimize, I trimmed it down a lot to make it more readable while still getting the point accross.

I'm basically seeing that theres the same 'group by' logic going on in the top level query and all three subqueries, and these columns are also the parameters for the 'inner join' logic. The thing is, I'm not sure how to optimize this, although I can imagine that there must be some simpler way to achieve the same result.

Involved Tables: Invoice, InvoiceLine, ProductType

InvoiceLine is related to Invoice and ProductType through a foreign key

This query is supposed to compare a single invoice's summed invoiceline.click to the summed invoiceline.click of all other invoices, grouped by producttype.name and invoiceline.origin, and additionally also split up by invoice.final. So the result should look like:

Product Type | Origin | Clicks Reference Invoice | Clicks All Other Finalized Invoices | Clicks All Other Unfinalized Invoices

Let me emphasize that the query does work, but its too slow. Any tips on optimizing this thing?

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
DECLARE @endDate datetime;
DECLARE @refInvoiceGuid uniqueidentifier;

SET @startDate='2013-09-01 00:00:00';
SET @endDate='2013-09-30 23:59:59';
SET @refInvoiceGuid='34d03903-a2ad-49ae-bd72-e98b47cdbc52';

SELECT
    ProductType.Name,
    InvoiceLine.Origin,
    invRef.ClicksRef,
    invFinal.ClicksFinal,
    invNotFinal.ClicksNotFinal
FROM InvoiceLine
INNER JOIN ProductType ON InvoiceLine.ProductType_Ref = ProductType.Id
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            ProductType.Name AS ProductName,
            InvoiceLine.Origin AS Origin,
            SUM(InvoiceLine.Clicks) AS ClicksRef
        FROM InvoiceLine
        INNER JOIN ProductType ON InvoiceLine.ProductType_Ref = ProductType.Id
        INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.Id = InvoiceLine.Invoice_Ref
        WHERE
            InvoiceLine.BillingDate >= @startDate
            AND InvoiceLine.BillingDate <= @endDate
            AND Invoice.Guid = @refInvoiceGuid
        GROUP BY
            ProductType.Name, InvoiceLine.Origin
    ) invRef ON ProductType.Name = invRef.ProductName AND InvoiceLine.Origin = invRef.Origin
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ProductType.Name AS ProductName,
            InvoiceLine.Origin AS Origin,
            SUM(InvoiceLine.Clicks) AS ClicksFinal
        FROM InvoiceLine
        INNER JOIN ProductType ON InvoiceLine.ProductType_Ref = ProductType.Id
        INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.Id=InvoiceLine.Invoice_Ref AND Invoice.Final=1
        WHERE
            InvoiceLine.BillingDate >= @startDate
            AND InvoiceLine.BillingDate <= @endDate
            AND Invoice.Guid != @refInvoiceGuid
        GROUP BY
            ProductType.Name, InvoiceLine.Origin
    ) invFinal ON ProductType.Name = invFinal.ProductName AND InvoiceLine.Origin = invFinal.Origin
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ProductType.Name AS ProductName,
            InvoiceLine.Origin AS Origin,
            SUM(InvoiceLine.Clicks) AS ClicksNotFinal
        FROM InvoiceLine
        INNER JOIN ProductType ON InvoiceLine.ProductType_Ref = ProductType.Id
        INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.Id=InvoiceLine.Invoice_Ref AND Invoice.Final=0
        WHERE
            InvoiceLine.BillingDate >= @startDate
            AND InvoiceLine.BillingDate <= @endDate
            AND Invoice.Guid != @refInvoiceGuid
        GROUP BY
            ProductType.Name, InvoiceLine.Origin
    ) invNotFinal ON ProductType.Name = invNotFinal.ProductName AND InvoiceLine.Origin = invNotFinal.Origin
WHERE
    InvoiceLine.BillingDate >= @startDate
    AND InvoiceLine.BillingDate <= @endDate
GROUP BY
    ProductType.Name,
    InvoiceLine.Origin,
    invRef.ClicksRef,
    invFinal.ClicksFinal,
    invNotFinal.ClicksNotFinal
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've added an index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductOrigin] ON InvoiceLine (Invoice_Ref,BillingDate) INCLUDE (Origin,Clicks,ProductType_Ref);
```

And I've rewritten the query to be more compact (apparently this has equal performance):

```
SELECT
    ProductType.Name,
    InvoiceLine.Origin, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.Guid = @refInvoiceGuid THEN InvoiceLine.Clicks ELSE 0 END) AS ClicksRef,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.Guid <> @refInvoiceGuid AND Invoice.Final = 1 THEN InvoiceLine.Clicks ELSE 0 END) AS ClicksFinal,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Invoice.Guid <> @refInvoiceGuid AND Invoice.Final = 0 THEN InvoiceLine.Clicks ELSE 0 END) AS ClicksNotFinal
FROM InvoiceLine  
INNER JOIN ProductType ON InvoiceLine.ProductType_Ref = ProductType.Id
INNER JOIN Invoice ON Invoice.id = InvoiceLine.Invoice_Ref
WHERE InvoiceLine.BillingDate >= @startDate AND InvoiceLine.BillingDate <= @endDate
GROUP BY ProductType.Name, InvoiceLine.Origin
```

It appears to have increased in speed, and it has certainly increased in readability, but in reality it still takes 3 minutes to execute. Here are the statistics and the execution plan:

[image: Statistics and plan]

So if I understand the statistics correctly, the index seek is just taking a really long time? Any ideas on how to improve this? Or am I just reaching the point where there is too much data?

Here are some statistics of the index:

[image: Index]

And the table:

[image: Table]

The results of running 'set statistics io on':

```
(170 row(s) affected)
Table 'ProductType'. Scan count 0, logical reads 340, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'InvoiceLine'. Scan count 2741, logical reads 37444, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Invoice'. Scan count 1, logical reads 115, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

**UPDATE 2**

After reversing the order of the index columns:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProductOrigin] ON InvoiceLine (BillingDate,Invoice_Ref) INCLUDE (Origin,Clicks,ProductType_Ref);

(170 row(s) affected)
Table 'ProductType'. Scan count 0, logical reads 340, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'InvoiceLine'. Scan count 1, logical reads 28371, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Invoice'. Scan count 1, logical reads 115, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Execution plan with index seek statistics:

[image: Execution plan 2]

This has improved performance significantly (we've gone from 170 seconds to 15 seconds). Thank you for the help so far. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plan? Run ``set statistics io on`` then run the query and see what you get in the messages.

Comment: You might do it all at once using conditional sum: `sum(case when Invoice.Guid = @refInvoiceGuid then InvoiceLine.Clicks end) as ClicksRef`, `sum(case when Invoice.Guid != @refInvoiceGuid and Invoice.Final = 1 then InvoiceLine.Clicks end) as ClicksFinal`, `sum(case when Invoice.Guid != @refInvoiceGuid and Invoice.Final = 0 then InvoiceLine.Clicks end) as ClicksNotFinal`.

Comment: @acfrancis SQL Server suggest to add a nonclustered index on (Invoice_Ref,BillingDate) including the columns (Origin,ProductType_Ref,Clicks) which does speed up significantly. However, I also need to perform complex insert queries elsewhere in the application which are slowed down by this index.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović I tried this and although it is much easier on the eyes, it has the same performance.

Comment: OK, what about the messages from ``statistics io``?

Comment: An index on `BillingDate` should not slow down inserts noticeably. If it proves correct, you might try adding *include* containing all the columns from `InvoiceLine` you use in this query.

Comment: I've added an index and adjusted the query. I've also added a ton of statistics. See "Update 1". @acfrancis I've appended the results of statistics io to the post.

Comment: Try changing the index from ``Invoice_Ref,BillingDate`` to ``BillingDate,Invoice_Ref`` (reversing the order of the columns in the index).

Comment: @acfrancis According to the io statistics this does save a lot of scans and 1/3 of the logical reads for the InvoiceLine table. Testing performance now...

Comment: @acfrancis It appears to have improved performance quite a lot, see **update 2** in the post. I'm still wondering if we can't push it a bit farther?

Comment: Try adding ``OPTION(FORCE ORDER)`` to the end of the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startDate datetime;
DECLARE @endDate datetime;
DECLARE @refInvoiceGuid uniqueidentifier;

SET @startDate='2013-09-01 00:00:00';
SET @endDate='2013-09-30 23:59:59';
SET @refInvoiceGuid='34d03903-a2ad-49ae-bd72-e98b47cdbc52';
select p.Name,il1.origin,SUM(il1.Clicks) as ClicksRef,SUM(il2.Clicks) as ClicksFinal,
SUM(il3.Clicks) as ClicksNotFinal
from Invoice i 
inner join InvoiceLine il1 on il1.Invoice_Ref = i.Id
and il1.BillingDate >= @startDate AND il1.BillingDate <= @endDate AND i.Guid =       
@refInvoiceGuid
left join InvoiceLine il2 on il2.Invoice_Ref = il1.Invoice_Ref  and il2.Final=1 and    
il2.BillingDate = il1.BillingDate 
left join InvoiceLine il3 on il3.Invoice_Ref = il2.Invoice_Ref  and il3.Final=0 and    
il3.BillingDate = il1.BillingDate 
INNER JOIN ProductType p on il1.ProductType_Ref = p.Id
group by p.Name,il1.origin
```

Comment: Final is defined on the table Invoice, not InvoiceLine.

Comment: change the table and link condition accordingly,without having data and structure it is hard to work on it buddy....

Comment: I assume you've based your answer on the query in the post, where all the references to the column `Final` are stated as `Invoice.Final` so I thought the structure was clear enough. If you need more details just ask, buddy. ;) If I change the table and link conditions accordingly I end up with the same problem I had initially.